# Assign URL for IP Adress (IP adresses mapping to host names)

Tags: iis-7, mapping, host

How can I change domain name for ip address (192.164.5.19) to www.anyname.com?

Current I made a website and published it by using iis7. It is in the intranet. Now I want to access the website by a domain name and not by ip address.

can anyone help me for with this problem.

Note: The web-server were use is normal PC not a server.

Answer (score 2):

It is up to the administrator of the DNS authorative nameserver for the "anyname.com" domain.

Since this is an intranet application, this would likely be your companies IT department.

You can find out more information about that via a whois search, although for an intranet application it may not be much help. One example: [domaintools link](http://whois.domaintools.com/anyname.com)

Answer (score -1):

Add the ip adress to the hosts file from the computers who needs to reach the website. E.g. u can do the edit with a batch file.

Path:

> %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

add line: 192.164.5.19 www.anyname.com

Comment: I think this would work fine for testing on one or two machines, but it is not an appropriate way to deploy. That's what DNS and active directory are for.

Comment: I have added an answer. Unfortunately you can probably not do it yourself unless you are the DNS or windows active directory administrator.

Comment: If u have a windows system u have a file (%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts). You can edit it with administrator privileges (open editor as admin and then the file) and add the line i wrote in the solution. Now u can type the adress www.anyname.com in the browser and the website hosted at 192.164.5.19 will be shown.

Comment: Yes i m already open the file with notepad. But i m not find the ip address 192.164.5.19...please help me...

Comment: Where you dont find the adress? You said you can reach the website with this adress, right ? So you have to ADD the adress in the host-file. The adress is not listed in the file until u have added it.

Comment: I m add ready the line. But the web page is cannot browse. It show "404 The site you were looking for couln't be found"....

Comment: It is only can function in localhost. The another computer cannot access it...please help me...

Comment: yes u need to make the change on all computers who wants to reach the website. for expample u can roll out a new hosts file with a batch script ..